# How to copy style of DataGridTextColumn to DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-toolkit

In my Silverlight DataGrid, i want to copy style of DataGridTextColumn to DataGridTemplateColumn's CellTemplete. 
This way DataGridTemplateColumn will look exactly same as other DataGridTextColumns.
Is there a straight forward way to achieve this?

Comment: There's not too much styling in the textColumn afaik.. it's just a textblock with vertical/horizontal alignment, and a margin...